# List of all versioned files in subversion? (Remove files by name)

Tags: svn, grep, find

Some smart dude at the office managed to commit a whole bunch of 'backup' files (they start with `._`) to our subversion server.

Preferably I would like to delete these files using some basic bash script instead of going through the repository manually.

Is there any way I can get a list of all subversion versioned files inside a directory so I can do some basic grepping / svn deletes?

edit:

'svn list' isn't recursive and also seems to list directories, I need the kind of behavior like 'find'.

second edit:

Ok, the -R flag can make 'svn list' recursive... but how do I strip out directories?

Comment: By the way, if you can convince your office, I'd recommend moving to a more modern VCS, such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: We've moved to git almost a year ago ;)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even realize how old this question was, someone added an answer so it moved up to the top and I saw it `:P`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only in one commit (or series of commits) then use *svn merge* to undo it.

If the user has been doing it across several commits and you're on Linux:

First check that this properly lists the files you want to delete:

```
find . -name '._*'
```

Then actually invoke svn to delete them:

```
find . -name '._*' -exec svn rm {} \;
```

Check svn status, commit if good.

Disclaimer: I have not tested the commands so beware.

I think those are Mac backup files it makes automatically.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks :) And yeah, the guy is using a mac.

Answer (score 6):

```
svn list -R
```

lists all files and directory recursively

Comment: Works, but slow :-(

Answer (score 4):

> how do I strip out directories?

The key is to observe the directories will end with a slash.

You can then use grep.

```
svn list -R my_svn_dir | grep -v '/$'
```