# SVN - show versioned local files only (command line)?

Tags: svn, command-line

I have a folder, versioned under SVN, with let's say 100 of files which are not under revision control - and about 10 that are.

On svn, version 1.6.6, if I type `svn status`, I get unversioned files with a question mark, `?`, or the modified/added files `M`/`A` - but I cannot see local files that are versioned, but haven't changed. `svn list` goes online, and retrieves say names of, say, four versioned files (but not all ten).

Is there a command I can use on the command line, so svn lists which files are under version control in a given local directory?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all versioned files in subversion? (Remove files by name)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634109/list-of-all-versioned-files-in-subversion-remove-files-by-name)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`svn ls` will list all files. If you are not seeing all the files that you expect, maybe they are not in the latest revision, in which case specify the revision using `--revision`, or probably they are within folders and hence you will have to include `--recursive`.

Otherwise, if you don't want to use `svn ls`, you will can write a one liner in bash so that you can subtract the output of normal `ls` and the `svn status` entries for untracked files.

Comment: Many thanks for that @manojlds - `svn ls`, being (I guess) an alias for `svn list`, still gives me only 4 files out of 10 on the mentioned directory...There could be a typo up there, since "_Subcommand 'list' doesn't accept option '--version'_" - however, the option `--revision` did work for me: as soon as I specified the revision by number, I got all 10 files back :) Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau - Yeah, I don't know why I typed version!

Comment: Is there a way to list the "staged" files?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is indeed running the command:

```
svn list --recursive .
```

However, this is rather slow. I have a large SVN repo with **26559** files of total size **7 GB**, and this command takes almost **4 minutes**.

---

Modern SVN client stores information about working copy in [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) database, so it is rather easy to hack it.
Here is a python script which extracts the list of versioned files in less than a second (works on SVN 1.9.5):

```py
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('.svn/wc.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM NODES")
data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    filename = row[1]
    if len(filename.strip()) == 0:
        continue
    print(filename)
```

Of course, this is an unsupported hack, so it can easily break. Most likely changing minor version of SVN WC is enough to break it. Also, I have no idea how this solution interacts with complicated features like externals, some sparse/mixed checkouts, and whatever other crazy things SVN allows.